# V-img vuetify, не работает с SSR?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify, ssr

Делаю проект на nuxt, для ui использую vuetify.
Решил использовать имеющиеся v-img. При инспекции генерируемого сервером кода увидел что не генерируется тег img(если смотреть через page source), если смотреть через консоль уже на открытом сайте, данный тег генерируется корректно.
Как быть с v-img и ssr? Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

```
<v-img
            :src="product.image"
            lazy-src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
            aspect-ratio="1"
            class="grey lighten-2"
            max-width="500"
            max-height="300"
        >
            <template v-slot:placeholder>
                <v-row class="fill-height ma-0" align="center" justify="center">
                    <v-progress-circular
                        indeterminate
                        color="grey lighten-5"
                    ></v-progress-circular>
                </v-row>
            </template>
        </v-img>
```

Answer (score 1):

Оберните вашу картинку в функцию `require()`.
Пример: `:src="require(product.image)"`

Второй вариант это обернуть `v-img` в `no-ssr` тэг.

Третий вариант это использовать папку `static` для хранения картинок, если вы используете картинки локально.

-static
--img

Пример пути: `src="img/product-image.jpg"`